# mail reader that uses gzipped archives from http instead of an nntp server

Tags: mailing-list, nntp

Is there a mail client that can be configured to use gzipped archives of mailing lists directly from where the mailing list is hosted rather than a central nntp server ? 
nntp is either not free, or slow in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

i guess i can open the unzipped gz file as a text file in emacs. 
turn on rmail-mode.
M-x undigestify-rmail-message
and rmail is ready to go... 
now i just need to right a download (wget or downloadthemall) and 

unzip script followed by 
concatenating the mail files...

```
gzip -d *.gz ; cat *.txt > allinone.txt
```

then can view in emacs as above or move into thunderbird local directory, for easy viewing / searching.